# Laravel 5.3 Notification - notify using only email address

Tags: laravel, notifications

I have an input field in my app for external email and i want to send a Notification on that email.

The problem is that this email can be outside of my app so i can't use $user->notify().

Is there a way to send a notification using only email address??

Answer (score 59, accepted):

With Laravel 5.5 and above you can send "On Demand Notifications" using the **Notification** facade:

```
Notification::route('mail', 'taylor@laravel.com')->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

[Topic on Official Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#on-demand-notifications)

Answer (score 26):

You can easily create a temporary User instance with the email address.

```
(new User)->forceFill([
    'name' => 'Their name',
    'email' => 'email@example.com',
])->notify(new MailMessage);
```

Comment: Attachments are part of the MailMessage class. You can add attachments or display in-line attachments; https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#attachments.

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.4 and  this solution don't work for, there is anyone can help me please

Comment: I dont believe this works when the notification is going to be queued. The temporary model has no ID so it has nothing to hydrate when the notification is picked up by a queue worker.

Comment: this works for me only if I add a dummy 'id'